# Crawl Search SharePoint 2007

Tags: 2007, search-results, crawl-rules

On our Crawl Rules we have excluded the following:

*://*allitems.aspx
*://*editform.aspx
*://*dispform.aspx
*://*my-sub.aspx
*://*mod-view.aspx

However on our search result it's still included, would you know any fix to this issues?

Comment: Have you run a run a full crawl?

Comment: @MatthewMcDermott after posting this question our search was unable to crawl those excluded pages. But I'll still need to monitor this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you change the rules you have to run a full crawl, back in 2007 sometimes two full crawls.